# Modulus simplication for $x$

Tags: absolute-value

$||x-1|-2|=|x-3|$. 
Find the value of $x$.
In my attempt I got the critical values of the expression as $1$ and $3$. 
But I’m not sure is we can just not consider the $2$ in the LHS.

My steps are Case 1: when $x>3$, $x-1-2=x-3$, $0=0$

Case 2: $1<x<3$, $X-1-2=-x+3 \implies 2x=6 \implies x= 3$

Case 3: $x<1$, $-x+1-2=-x+3$. Not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by not considering the $2$?

Comment: I’m not sure if my steps toward finding the value are correct as the 2 on LHS in mod is still present.

Comment: Can you please edit the question showing your steps?

Comment: Your list of cases looks incomplete. The first case you develop looks correct. For the others, check the answers below.

Comment: Your calculation in Case 2 are incorrect, if $1<x<3 \implies 0<x-1<2$, therefore $||x-1|-2|=|(x-1)-2|=2-(x-1)$

Comment: So, from your calculations you see $x \geq 1$ works

Comment: I see why made the mistake. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

You have found the critical value to be $1$ and $3$, that's great, don't worry too much and work it out and see what needs to be done.

Consider $x<1$:

$$||x-1|-2|<|x-3|$$

$$|(1-x)-2|<3-x$$

$$|-1-x|<3-x$$

$$|x+1|<3-x$$

Now, as you see, you might need a new condition, just impose it and handle things as it comes by, now consider $x<-1$ and $x>-1$.

Move on to consider $1<x<3$, $x>3$, $x=1$, $x=3$ as well.

Comment: I see thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Just sketch the graphs $y=||x-1|-2|$ and $y=|x-3|$.

To draw $y=|x-3|$, first draw $y=x-3$ then reflect the negative $y$-region up over the $x$-axis. (In other words, fold the graph up over the $x$-axis.) Leave the positive $y$-region as it is.

To draw $y=||x-1|-2|$, first draw $y=x-1$, then fold it up over the $x$-axis, slide the whole thing down by 2, then fold it up over the $x$-axis.

It should be quite obvious that $x \ge 1$ solves $||x-1|-2|=|x-3|$.

Answer (score 0):

You must do case work. If $$x\geq 1$$ then we get $$\vert{x-3\vert}=|x-3|$$ which is true.
If $$x<1$$ then we have $$|-x+1-2|=|x-3|$$, can you solve this equation?